# Given a grammar, generate the LR(1) items

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, lr-grammar, lr1

I am working on LR(1) items and I am having a bit of doubt and hoping someone can clarify for me. Given the following grammar, I must generate the LR(1) items. I generated the first item but am unsure if its correct, so before I continue, I want to make sure I have the first one correct. If anyone can help me/clarify for me, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you. Here is what I have:

```
Augmented Grammar:
S' -> S
S -> [ ]
S -> [ S ]
S -> S S

I0: S' -> • S, $
    S  -> • [ ], $
    S  -> • [ S ], $
    S  -> • S S, $
```

Comment: That's correct. But your grammar is ambiguous, so you're going to end up with conflicts sooner or later.

Comment: Using an online parser generator I just found, it gave me this result for I0:{[S’ -> .S, $]; [S -> .[ ], $/[]; [S -> .[ S ], $/[]; [S -> .S S, $/[]}, Im not sure where it got the $/[ ] from. Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't check the lookaheads, sorry. In `S -> S S`, the first `S` on the right-hand side can be followed by FIRST(S), and FIRST(S) is obviously `[`.

Comment: How about the ] , where does that one come from? I'm just a little confused as to why its not just $. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the ] is punctuation. That is, it is closing the open bracket started by `[ S -> ...`

Comment: oh! ok, that makes sense. Thank you.